# Getting one Extra row when exporting SSRS report to Excel

Tags: excel, export, reporting-services

I have a simple Reporting Services report, a simple table, created with BIDS 2005, with the report wizard.

I run the report on a RS2008 R2 server as is and it renders perfectly.

When I export to Excel, an extra row is appended just below the table. The row is hidden and has a heigth of 409.5.

Where that row comes from ?
How to get rid of it ?

*nb - no extra row if run on a RS2005 server

Comment: I have the same problem with a report created with BIDS 2008, run a RS2008 server.

Answer (score 4):

The only way I found to eliminate the hidden row is change the layout of the report. I increased the height of all rows of from 0,53333cm to 0,538cm.
Anything less than 0,538cm doesn’t solve the issue.

According to Microsoft, the goal when exporting to excel is to match the visual appearance of the report as close as possible. The excel output may have unexpected things like extra rows or columns or merged cells as part of the process to match the layout.

Comment: Important to note here is that the value of `0.538cm` isn't some magic figure that will always work. It's highly dependent on the font type(s) and size(s) present in the rows. For instance, I needed to change the row height to `0.7cm` from `0.6cm` to get it to work.

Comment: This has racked my brain for years. I had a field that contained multiple column values and had the setting CanGrow = True. Even when everything appeared to be lined up, I could never figure out why extra rows would still appear. On a whim, I decided to revisit this issue and the first stack overflow thread was this. My magic number was 0.6in.  Thanks! :)

Answer (score 3):

Changing the tablix location to 0cm, 0cm , will fix the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I was running into this issue and tried all the posted solutions I could find, but none worked for me. To be more specific, after exporting the SSRS report to excel there was an extra row that contained duplicated data from the first row of the group. This extra row was contained in a group that could be toggled and when that group was collapsed that extra row was still showing instead of nothing.

This was the report layout looked like before I made the change.
[image: Report Before]

What I had to do was add an extra row above and outside the nested grouping by right clicking the group box and selecting "Add row" -> "Outside Group - Above"
[image: Add row outside group]

Here is the report after.
[image: Report After]

After adding the rows outside the group there was no duplicated data in an extra row.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the Size of report(not table) to 0.0pt, 0.0pt.It will automatically set it to minimum required.